# Python & Pandas: Pendant for R/dplyr .rds format

Tags: python, pandas, serialization, dataframe, deserialization

What's the closest pendant / alternative for the `.RDS` format [known from R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readRDS.html) for `Python` respectively the Pandas `DataFrame`?

I tried `to_pickle()` as listed in the [`DataFrame` documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#id12) but it lacks to property to be smaller than the corresponding `.csv` file holding the same contents.

```
df = pd.get_dummies(pd.Series(list('abca')))
df.to_csv("tmp.csv")       # 44 Bytes
df.to_pickle("tmp.pickle") # 682 Bytes
```

I'm looking for **fast** (save time writing and reading in comparision to `.CSV`) and **compressed** (save disk space in comparision to `.CSV`) way to (de)serialize Pandas `DataFrame`s.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

pandas can export to [`HDF5`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-hdf5), which is faster and more compact than CSV. Sometimes it has problems with mixed types, but those problems exist with CSV as well.

You also have to be careful comparing filesizes with small datasets. The overhead for compression might make the file larger for smaller datasets